# How do I accomplish this thick offset underline in CSS?

Tags: css, underline

I'm trying to accomplish this underline style but everything I try isn't working. Here's the link to the actual website I found this on. https://www.timeout.com/newyork/music/best-music-videos-of-all-time

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can add a div under the words and give it a `margin-top: -10` or some other negative value instead of using a border

Comment: On that site, it's a child element of an `<h3>` and it has `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(211,26,34,0.5) 0%, rgba(211,26,34,0.5) 100%); background-position: 0 0.84em;    background-repeat: repeat-x; background-size: 1px 15px;` [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/yfg6ec5a/). See the highly useful [Chrome Web Developer Tools - Viewing And Changing CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's best to show us what you've tried so we can help you understand the concept or correct any mistakes you made. The idea is to have the text with another element below it that has a negative top margin. There are other approaches to accomplish the same thing, each approach will have it's use case and pros/cons.

The concept looks like this in code:

```css
.border-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
    bla bla bla
  </h2>
  <div class='border-bottom'>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this look with a pseudo element by positioning it at the bottom of the "parent" element and setting it's `z-index` to `-1`.

See here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVNjLX

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
}

.link::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#0">
  Radiohead, Karma Police
</a>
```

Of course, you can play around with the values to get exactly the look you're after and even animate the pseudo element on hover, etc.

The website you referenced actually accomplishes this effect with a gradient background image on the element. Pretty slick.

You can check that out in action here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZKEwE